# Getting a warning about null values being eliminated from a SET, but there is no null value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I know what this warning means, however in this case there are definitely no null values.

The result also appears to be correct, but the warning makes me curious (and concerned) since it means there's something in play that I don't understand.

The warning is:

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Here's the statement:

```
UPDATE Contacts
SET IsActiveCampaignClient = 1,
    NeedsActiveCampaignSync = 1
FROM (
    SELECT dbo.Contacts.ID
    FROM dbo.Contacts
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Order_Batches ON dbo.Order_Batches.EnteredByContactID = dbo.Contacts.ID
    GROUP BY dbo.Contacts.ID
    HAVING (COUNT(dbo.Order_Batches.ID) > 0)
    ) i
WHERE i.ID = Contacts.ID
```

As you can see, this is an UPDATE statement where I needed to do some join logic, and the COUNT() statement must be the problem. But if I take that nested SELECT out and run it by itself, there are no nulls in the result:

ID
37
39
52
54
79
81

I assume there's something about how this nested select works that I don't understand. I've tried looking at execution plans and pulling this apart in various ways to reveal a null value or some other problem. I've tried making tweaks to the statement to try and get a null to appear - no luck.

So, to be clear, I would like to understand why this message occurs, but only when the query is nested inside an UPDATE statement's FROM clause.

Comment: `COUNT(dbo.Order_Batches.ID)` will produce the warning whilst being used with a left join, where the counted object does not exist. Try querying `SELECT dbo.Contacts.ID,dbo.Order_Batches.ID
    FROM dbo.Contacts
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Order_Batches ON dbo.Order_Batches.EnteredByContactID = dbo.Contacts.ID` and see for nulls

Comment: to update the contacts table whenever there is an order does not need aggregation. just use `exists`... unless if you are getting the number of orders to the contacts table

Comment: @AjayGupta So why does it only show the warning when I run that inside of an update statement, as shown above? If I take the select statement out and run it alone (including the JOIN and the COUNT, but in the FROM of an update statement), there is no warning. That's what  I want to understand. :)

Comment: If you're getting nulls in the `dbo.Order_Batches.ID` column in the query I've provided, then it'll give you a warning when you run the query `SELECT dbo.Contacts.ID
    FROM dbo.Contacts
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Order_Batches ON dbo.Order_Batches.EnteredByContactID = dbo.Contacts.ID
    GROUP BY dbo.Contacts.ID
    HAVING (COUNT(dbo.Order_Batches.ID) > 0)` Remember to see the messages tab.

Comment: @AjayGupta No nulls I can detect, and no messages in the messages tab either! I included the results of the query above. Also...

Comment: @AjayGupta I modified the query so that I could see the results of the COUNT, just in case it sometimes had nulls, but it shows 0 in that case. Of course, in this case, where there are no matches on the Order_Batches side of the join, that would actually come across as NULL and that would go into the count and, I guess, produce a 0. So the message makes sense. But I wonder why I only see the warning when this is nested in an UPDATE?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue using a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Does not need aggregation if you are ensuring that there is at least an order by the contact to update this. Use `EXISTS` instead.

```
UPDATE c
SET IsActiveCampaignClient = 1,
    NeedsActiveCampaignSync = 1
FROM  Contacts c
WHERE exists (
  (
    SELECT 1   -- making sure there is at least an order
    FROM Order_Batches o
    where o.EnteredByContactID = c.ID
    )
```

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but I mainly want to know where that message is coming from for my own knowledge. :)

Comment: Firstly your query may have worked but it is programmatically incorrect. There is no point for an explanation to be honest. Just a waste of time.